# How to scroll listbox automatically when Scrollviewer present above it has finished scrolling

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, scrollviewer

I am developing a windows application,

I have a Parent scroll viewer and inside it there is child scrollviewer and a listbox.

I want to know if there is a way to scroll a listbox(which is fixed in the footer of page) automatically as soon as the scrollviewer present above it has ended its scrolling.

Attached below is the reference image.

[image]

Please help as I am new to windows development.

**Update1:**

Adding the below code as basis:

```
 <ScrollViewer Name="Scroll1">//parent scrollViewer
 <Grid  Name="ScrollContent">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="500"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ScrollViewer  Name="A" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">//child scrollViewer
     ---//Code to display Title1
     <Listbox>
     ---
     ---
     </Listbox>
     --
     </ScrollViewer>

     <Grid Name="B" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
     ---//Code to display Title2
     <Listbox>
     ---
     ---
     </Listbox>
     </Grid>

 </Grid>
 </ScrollViewer>
```

Please let me know if there is any workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to take to achieve this:

1. Get the `Height` of the `ScrollViewer` and save in a `variable`.

   2. Set an `event` for when the `ScrollViewer` view changes.
   3. Inside 2 above, run an `if` statement to check if the `ScrollViewer` `vertical-offset` if equal to the `Height`. I.e if you've scrolled to the end.
   4. Hide/collapse visibility of the `ScrollViewer` to enable your `ListBox` scroll.

If you do not want to hide the visibility of the `ScrollViewer` at all, you must then utilize the flexibility of `Grid` children properties.

Do these in xaml

1. Place your `ScrollViewer` and `ListBox` inside a `Grid`.
2. Define the `Vertical-Definitions` of the `Grid` and set the first `Row` `Height` as `Auto`.
3. Set the second `Row` `Height` as `*`.
4. Give the `ScrollViewer` `Row` `0` and the `ListBox` (with a fixed height) `Row` `1`.

In c#
In the `ScrollViewer` `ScrollChanged` `event`, once the `vertical-offset` is equal to the `Height` of the `Grid` created above, modify the `Grid` properties by reversing the amount of space they have on the screen. I.e change the Scroll Viewer `Row` `Height` to `*` (fixed) and change the `ListBox` `Row` `Height` to `Auto`.

Provide feedback on how this goes.

If you have provided some codes to show how you've tried to fix this yourself, perhaps I would have modified the errors in it. But I hope  my answer helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't want to Hide/collapse the visibility of the scrollviewer.I want the listbox to scroll as soon as the scrollviewer above it has finished scrolling.

Comment: I can't modify the row height of listbox because I want it to be visible at the bottom of page.I want the Listbox to scroll along with parent scrollViewer as soon as child scrollviewer has finished scrolling.